# how to add radio buttons in jenkins while rebuild for multipipeline branch job

Tags: javascript, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to add radio button or dropdown in my Jenkins project while giving `Build with parameter` option.

I am adding parameters to Jenkins like below:

### Jenkins File

```js
#!groovy

properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty',
    parameterDefinitions: [[$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'RELEASE_VERSION', defaultValue: '1.0.0'],
    [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'packages', defaultValue: 'true'],
    [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'samples', defaultValue: 'true'],
    [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'branchName', defaultValue: 'master'],
    [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'FROM_VERSION', defaultValue: '']]],
    [$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '7', artifactNumToKeepStr: '10', daysToKeepStr: '15', numToKeepStr: '10']]])

node('Cloud_mahcineName') {
    try {
        deleteDir();

        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout scm;
        }

        stage('Install') {
            runShell('npm -v');
        }

        stage('Test') {
            runShell('npm run test');
        }
}
```

### which gives like below UI:

[image]

### But i want something like below:

[image: expected]

Answer (score 0):

Below link helps me to achieve my requirement:

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/groovy-script-to-show-only-selected-item/5569#5569?newreg=4660fe5e02a24a86858c98e3465db5e0

```js
[$class: 'ChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_RADIO', description: '',
   filterLength: 1, filterable: false, name: 'samples',
    randomName: 'choice-parameter-1683871426502398',
     script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: true, 
      script: 'return "Error"'],
       script: [classpath: [], sandbox: true,
        script: '''return[
              \'true\',\'false\']''']]],
```

To add dropdown:

```js
properties(
    [
            [
                    $class              : 'ParametersDefinitionProperty',
                    parameterDefinitions: [
                            [
                                    $class     : 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                    choices    : 'aaa\nbbb',
                                    description: 'select your choice : ',
                                    name       : 'choice1'
                            ]
```

### Also is there any way to add validation like form validation?

Comment: I don't think its possible in Jenkins provided form but If you are using Jenkins scripted or declarative pipeline with If..else condition you can proceed and fail the build.

Comment: Hi @SamitKumarPatel, fyi   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183586/how-to-add-values-in-jenkins-dropdown-parameter-based-on-another-params

Comment: I meant form validation is not possible. 
Dropdown, Radio button as Jenkins Parameter is possible.